# Populating JTextField with Array data

Tags: java, arrays, swing, arraylist, jtextfield

I am making a program that lets you choose a player from a JComboBox drop down list that has values passed from an Array, this array is a converted ArrayList from a BBDDClass that contains values of players from a Player class.

JCombo:

```
          ArrayList<Player> arrayPlayers = new ArrayList<Player>();
          arrayPlayers = unaBBDD.arrayListPlayers();

          Player[] arrayCopy = new Player[arrayPlayers.size()];
          players = new JComboBox(arrayPlayers.toArray(arrayCopy));
          norte.add(players);
          players.addActionListener(this);

              } catch (Exception e) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," WRONG");
      }
```

BBDDClass:

```
      Connection conn = conexion();

      Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
      String players = "SELECT * FROM jugadores ORDER BY nombre";
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(players);

      ArrayList<Player> result = new ArrayList<Player>();

      while(rs.next()) {
         int cod = rs.getInt(1);
         String name = rs.getString(2);
         String proc = rs.getString(3);
         String height = rs.getString(4);
         int weight = rs.getInt(5);
         String pos = rs.getString(6);
         String team = rs.getString(7);
         Player onePlayer = new Player(cod, name, proc, height, weight, pos, team);
         result.add(onePlayer);

      }

      conn.close();

      return result;

   }
```

Player class:

```
   public Player(int code, String name, String procedence, String height, int weight, String position, String team) {
      this.code = code;
      this.name = name;
      this.procedence = procedence;
      this.height = height;
      this.weight = weight;
      this.position = position;
      this.team = team;
   }

   // Method toString
   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return name + " (" + team + ")";
   }
}
```

What I need to do is get the height, weight, position and team of each player and update the text of a JTextField for each stat.

I am not sure how to call each value to update each textField if anyone can give me any pointers?

I know I would have to use setText to add the values to each textfield inside the ActionPerformed method but I am not sure how to call each individual value from the arrays/other class.
[image: Here is an image of the result so far with the textfields I want to update.]

Comment: You can pass that text field as parameter to other methods, or make it a global variable

Comment: Posting a [mcve] would make it easier for me to help you. Maybe you can [edit] your question and post such an example? Also, I don't have access to your database, so in your [mcve] maybe just add two or three hard-coded `Player` instances. By the way, if you look at the code for class `JComboBox` you will see that the constructor that takes a `Object` array parameter, converts that array to a `Vector`. I suggest you store the `Player` details you retrieve from the database directly into a `Vector` which would save a lot of unnecessary conversions between data structures.